# Are there good methods for removing lines?

Tags: python, opencv

[image: background]

[image: object image]

I want to eliminate gray lines in 16 bit image you can see.

Final goal is remove line in object image(second image) with background image(first image).

I thought it need FFT, but i don't know how FFT applied. There will be other ways, too.

please help me.

Comment: Those lines make a noticeable frequency in the dft magnitude image, by masking those parts in the dft image, and doing inverse dft on the frequency image, lines would go off, without bluring other parts of the image. This source will help you to work with DFT: https://docs.opencv.org/master/de/dbc/tutorial_py_fourier_transform.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way using Python/OpenCV is to use morphology close multiple times with a small vertical rectangular kernel.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('lines.png')

# do morphology multiple times to remove horizontal lines
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,5))
result = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = 9)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("lines_removed.png", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

However, it will modify the image everywhere slightly

Comment: Thank you for your hard work!! I will apply it by reference. However, this method blurs the shape of the rat, so there is some inconvenience.